# Excel обрезает текст при вставке

Tags: excel, ms-access, office

Если делать Copy/Paste из Excel в Access и наоборот, то текст свыше 255 символов обрезается до 255...

Можно ли этого как-нибудь избежать?

Comment: Ограничения длины текстовой строки. Макросом можно.

Comment: Странно, хотя сама строка может иметь >255 символов.